# Destructor of dynamically allocated array causing Heap buffer error

Tags: c++, console-application

So I have an assignement to write a version of the vector library without using it. I need to use dynamically allocated arrays, However their destructor is causing errors. Here is my code:

```
    class orderedVector {

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const orderedVector&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, orderedVector&);

public:
    orderedVector(int = 9);
    ~orderedVector();
    int getSize() const;
    int getCapacity() const;
    void doubleCapacity();
    bool find(int) const;
    void insert(int);
    void remove(int);
    void findSum(int);

private:
    int size;
    int capacity;
    int* ptr;
};

orderedVector::orderedVector(int c) {
    capacity = c;
    size = 0;
    ptr = new int[c];
}

orderedVector::~orderedVector() {
    delete[] ptr;
}

int orderedVector::getSize() const {
    return size;
}

int orderedVector::getCapacity() const {
    return capacity;
}

void orderedVector::doubleCapacity() {

    int newCapacity = capacity * 2;

    orderedVector temp(capacity);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp.ptr[i] = ptr[i];
    }
    ptr = new int[newCapacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ptr[i] = temp.ptr[i];
    }

    capacity = newCapacity;
}

bool orderedVector::find(int number) const {
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        if (number == ptr[i])
            return true;
    return false;
}

void orderedVector::insert(int number){

    if (find(number)) {
        return;
    }

    if (size == capacity)
        doubleCapacity();

    if (size == 0)
        ptr[0] = number;

    else {
        int checkpoint = size;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (number < ptr[i]) {
                checkpoint = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = size-1; i >= checkpoint; i--) {
            ptr[i + 1] = ptr[i];
        }

        ptr[checkpoint] = number;
    }
    size++;
}           

void orderedVector::remove(int number) {

    if (find(number) == false)
        cout << "Number does not exist in the vector.\n";
    else {
        int checkpoint = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
            if (ptr[i] == number)
                checkpoint = i;

        for (int i = checkpoint; i < size; i++)
            ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
    }
    ptr[size] = 0;
    size--;
}

void orderedVector::findSum(int number) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= size; j++) {
            if (ptr[i] + ptr[j] == number) {
                cout << "The two numbers that have a sum of " << number
                    << " are " << ptr[i] << " and " << ptr[j] << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "No two numbers found that give a sum of " << number << endl;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const orderedVector& vector) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size; i++)
        output << vector.ptr[i] << "    ";

    output << endl;
    return output;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& input, orderedVector& vector) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.capacity; i++) {
        input >> x;
        vector.insert(x);
    }
    return input;
}
```

It appears that when I initialize an element, and the array is completely filled, I get this error:
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED, CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

I know it's the destructor because when I remove it, no errors occur.
Also, when my vector element is not completely filled (the capacity is bigger than the size), no error occurs. 
I would like to know how to fix this, or how the delete operator works in general, and why it causes an error if I fill my dynamically created array.

Comment: The first step to fix this is to read stackoverflow.com's [help], take the [tour], and to learn [ask] questions here that are on-topic. Your question is off-topic because it fails to meet all requirements of a [mre].

Comment: `capacity = c + 1;`? Why? That's just wrong in your code, since you only allocate an array of size `c`

Comment: Additionally both your `find` functions iterate past the `size`, reading either uninitialized values or past the bounds of the array

Comment: A lot of things might go wrong when using dynamic memory allocation, but for certain you are violating [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), which might give the results you are describing (the error goes away when remove destructor and introduce memory leak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic allocation may be deallocated at most once. As such, when you deallocate in a destructor, it is important to establish a class invariant that at most one instance uniquely owns the same pointer. If such invariant is violated, then the destructors of those instances may attempt to `delete` same pointer twice, which leads to undefined behaviour. Which is bad.

Your class `orderedVector` indeed deallocates in its destructor. However, the (implicitly generated) copy constructor of the class copies the member variable, which violates the class invariant of unique ownership.

You failed to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but it is reasonable to guess that your program makes a copy of an instance of `orderedVector`, leading to undefined behaviour due to multiple `delete` of the same pointer.

The solution is to either make the class non-copyable and non-movable, or follow the rule of 3 (or 5) i.e. implement the copy (and move) constructors and assignment operators in a way that enforces the invariant of unique ownership.